# What does "dematriculate" mean outside of an academic context?

Tags: meaning

In *Tintin and the Secret of Literature* by Tom McCarthy (Berkeley, CA: Counterpoint, 2008), McCarthy writes:

> The books are full of erasure: dematriculated planes; wiped runways; wiped memories; a ship whose name (*Karaboudjan*) has been removed and replaced; a city whose name (*Los Dopicos*) is removed, replaced, removed and replaced again. [p.30]

I *think* "planes" here means "aeroplanes" (there's precedence for this usage earlier in the book) rather than geometric planes (although I'm not sure about this). But what does "dematriculated" mean? I am familiar with "matriculation" in an academic context—meaning something like enrollment as a student in a university. *De*matriculation looks like it's the inverse of this process. But I can't see how that makes sense as applied to either geometric planes or to aircraft.

Wiktionary[1](https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/matriculate) suggests that etymologically matriculate derives from "*matriculare*" ("to register") itself ultimately from "*matrix*" ("list"). This makes me think that "dematriculated" *might* mean something like "unregistered", although this might be a bit of a stretch.

Comment: I think 'unregistered planes' sounds perfectly fitting: the subject is erasure, and wiped runways are similarly forms of removing registrations. In Tintin albums this often occurs when transportation is used for illegal activities.

Comment: @Joachim Perhaps 'deregistered' rather than 'unregistered'. A new plane which has not yet been registered is 'unregistered', a used one which has been registered but has had its registration cancelled or expunged in some way is 'deregistered'. As plane manufacturers are usually large organisations it's probably easier to deregister an old plane than to get a new plane into service without registering it.